# Initialising struct through a function whose members are dynamic arrays

Tags: c, pointers, struct, initialization, malloc

I have the following struct definition (names have been generalised):

```
typedef struct structure{
    int *array1;
    int *array2;
} structure_t;
```

I need to initialise this struct data structure through a function which takes in the sizes of the two arrays as parameters. The function returns a pointer to that data structure and NULL on fail.

I am getting confused on how to go about this. I know that I cannot return a pointer of a locally declared struct, and I also know that I need to dynamically allocate memory for the two members array1 and array2, since the size is not known on compile time (it's inputted by this user). I have tried the following:

```
structure_t* init(int size1, int size2)
{
    structure_t *st = malloc(sizeof (structure_t));

    if(st == NULL) return NULL;

    st->array1 = malloc((sizeof (int))*size1);
    st->array2 = malloc((sizeof (int))*size2);

    return st;
}
```

I have checked and everything is being initialised. But then when I come to free the memory it is not working properly, as only the pointer to array1 is being changed to NULL.

```
bool destroy(strcuture_t *st)
{
    free(st->array1);
    free(st->array2);
    free(st);

    if (st == NULL)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `free()` will not, and furthemore can not change the value of the pointer you pass to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`free` does not change the value of the pointer passed to it. It cannot, as it receives only the value and not a reference to the pointer.

To record that a pointer no longer points to valid memory, you can set the pointer to `NULL` yourself after calling `free`, as with:

```
free(st);
st = NULL;
```

Further, once the memory pointed to by `st` is freed, the C standard does not define the behavior of accessing `st->array1` or `st->array2` or even of using the value of `st` at all. There is no reason to expect that checking `st->array1` or `st->array2` for a null pointer will produce any particular result. The comparison may evaluate to true, may evaluate to false, may cause your program to abort, or may cause your program to misbehave in other ways.

Comment: Thank you so much! This was super helpful, and I have replaced the code in my destroy function with yours and just returned true (it must return a bool since this is for a school thing and we have to stick to the given function prototypes). Also, just to confirm, my intisialtion is correct then, right?

Comment: @MariahZammit: The initialization looks correct to me. However, it is preferable to change `structure_t *st = malloc(sizeof (structure_t));` to `structure_t *st = malloc(sizeof *st);` because this bases the size on the object being assigned rather than on a second typing of the type. That reduces typing errors (such as having `structA_t` where `structB_t` is intended) and automatically adjusts if the type of `st` is ever changed. Similarly, the other assignments should be `st->array1 = malloc(size1 * sizeof *st->array1);` and `st->array2 = malloc(size2 * sizeof *st->array2);`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and detailed answers :)